# Enterprise Architect scripting with java - add CustomProperty

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to add a legend to my activity diagram, which will be generate programatically by java and the ea-api.
I already know how to create the legend element and show it in the diagram (Type: "Text" und Subtype: 76):

```
Element legend = elements.AddNew("Color Legend", "Text");
elements.Refresh();

legend.SetSubtype(76);
legend.Update();

//Show in diagram
DiagramObject diagramObject = diagramObjects.AddNew("l=0; r=100; t=0; b=-100;", "");
diagramObjects.Refresh();
// reference the DiagramObject to the before created element
diagramObject.SetElementID(legend.GetElementID());
```

But this is only an empty legend. So my question is, how to add an CustomProperty to the CustomProperties. My first approach was the following code:

```
Collection<CustomProperty> customProperties = legend.GetCustomProperties();
CustomProperty cp = customProperties.AddNew("LegendEntryTest", "Back_Ground_Color=2124031;");
customProperties.Refresh();
legend.Update();
```

But this don't work, the legend is still empty:(

Here is an example-legend:

[image]

Regards,
Phil

**EDIT**
With the help of Geert Bellekens I had solved my problem. Now I use the repository.Execute(String sqlStmt) method to insert the custom property in the `t_xref`.
The following code is a small example how it work's:

```
//get elementGUID of legend
String legendGUID = legend.GetElementGUID();

//create the description value for one custom_property
String name="TestColor1";
String color="3381504";
int customPropertyIndex = 0;

String description = "@PROP=@NAME="+name+"@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#="+color+";#Pen_Color#=16777215;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT="+customPropertyIndex +"@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"

//add description part for the legend
description += "@PROP=@NAME=Legend@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_STYLE_SETTINGS@ENDTYPE;@VALU=@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"

String sqlInsertStmt="INSERT INTO t_xref "
            + "(" 
                + "Client,"
                + "XrefID,"
                + "Type,"
                + "Name,"
                + "Visibility,"
                + "Partition,"
                + "Supplier,"
                + "Description"
            + ") "
            + " VALUES ("
                +"'"+legendGUID+ "',"
                + "'{"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"}',"
                + "'element property',"
                + "'CustomProperties',"
                + "'Public',"
                + "'0',"
                + "'&lt;none&gt;',"
                + "'"+description+"'"
            + ");"
                ;

repository.Execute(sqlInsertStmt);
```

With `java.util.UUID` I generate a new GUID for the field `XrefID`.

By the way: To convert a RGB-color to that which will accept by Enterprise Architect you can use the following formular:

```
 int colorValue = color.getRed() + (color.getGreen() * 256)
            + (color.getBlue() * 256 * 256);
```

(RGB Color Model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add the custom property using code, but I'm pretty sure you'll have to resort to an SQL hack to be able to fill in all the required details.
If you check the database you'll find that a all the custom properties of your legend are stored in a single row in the table t_xref.
The column Client contains the t_object.ea_guid and the description column contains all the details of your custom properties.
I did a small test and this is what was stored in the description (I added newlines for the readability)

```
@PROP=@NAME=Wit@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#=16777215;#Pen_Color#=16777215;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT=0@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
@PROP=@NAME=rood@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#=255;#Pen_Color#=255;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT=1@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
@PROP=@NAME=blauw@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#=16711680;#Pen_Color#=16711680;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT=2@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
@PROP=@NAME=Legend@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_STYLE_SETTINGS@ENDTYPE;@VALU=@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
```

If I where you I would use Repository.Execute() with a dirty SQL insert statement to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your effort. I will try this on wednesday or thursday and give feedback:-)

Comment: Hello Geert Bellekens, do you know how I should fill the field `XrefID` in the table `t_xref?` Should I generate it? In the database script that field is "not null"-declared.

Comment: Yes, just generate a new GUID

Comment: Thank you very much Geert Bellekens. Now it work's!:-) I have edit my question with example-code for the solution.