# Enterprise Architect scripting with javascript - Add a legend to a diagram

Tags: javascript, enterprise-architect

I am trying to add a legend to a digram partly following question: [Enterprise Architect scripting with java - add CustomProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280146/enterprise-architect-scripting-with-java-add-customproperty) but I have  no luck in getting a visible legend on my diagram. Here is my code:

```
function addLegend()
{
   Repository.EnsureOutputVisible( "Script" );
   Repository.ClearOutput("Script");
   var pkg as EA.Package; 

   pkg = Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage();   
   elements = pkg.Elements;
   var legend = elements.AddNew('Diagram Legend', 'Text');

   legend.Subtype = 76;
   legend.Update();
   elements.Refresh();
   var diagram as EA.Diagram;

   diagram = Repository.GetDiagramByID(10);
   Session.Output(diagram.Name);
   diagramObjects = diagram.DiagramObjects;


   diagramObject = diagramObjects.AddNew("l=100; r=100; t=100; b=500;", "");
   diagramObject.ElementID = legend.ElementID;
   diagramObjects.Refresh();
   diagram.Update();
}
```

` 
As said no legend is displayed - any help appreciated. My EA version is 12.0.

Comment: l=100;r=100 means you're specifying a zero width. Try r=200.

Comment: Yes agree but the size given does not affect the result, actually the code supplied by Geert makes it work. Changing the r= to e.g. 1000 just moves the legend to the right  - apparently the size is not controlled by the parameters supplied to `AddNew.` but by the size of the title

Answer (score 1):

You don't save your newly created DiagramObject with a call to `Update()` and you don't need those calls to `Refresh()`

The call to update the diagram might also be undoing whatever you are trying to change to the diagram.
Try it with the following slightly changed code (untested)

```
function addLegend()
{
   Repository.EnsureOutputVisible( "Script" );
   Repository.ClearOutput("Script");
   var pkg as EA.Package; 

   pkg = Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage();   
   elements = pkg.Elements;
   var legend = elements.AddNew('Diagram Legend', 'Text');

   legend.Subtype = 76;
   legend.Update();
   var diagram as EA.Diagram;

   diagram = Repository.GetDiagramByID(10);
   Session.Output(diagram.Name);
   diagramObjects = diagram.DiagramObjects;


   diagramObject = diagramObjects.AddNew("l=100; r=100; t=100; b=500;", "");
   diagramObject.ElementID = legend.ElementID;
   diagramObject.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geert, your solution works, does the arguments to `Elements.AddNew()` and `DiagramObjects.AddNew()` have any significance and if yes are they documented somewhere?

Comment: There is some documentation, but not much. See http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/collection.html