# Enterprise Architect Scripting - Change Properties of Legends with SQL Injection

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to change the properties of my legend that I built with the following instruction:

[Enterprise Architect scripting with java - add CustomProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280146/enterprise-architect-scripting-with-java-add-customproperty/70331037#70331037)

Is there a list of properties I can change with this injection method?
Mainly I want to make the Background white and the border black.

I guess it should go within the

`@PROP=@NAME=Legend@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_STYLE_SETTINGS@ENDTYPE;@VALU=@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;`

I also tried opening the eap file via Microsoft Access and look it up in the tables, but this doesn´t seem to work (even with the Example.eap).

EA Version: 15.1

Atttempt:

```
var L5name = "Software (L5_Software_Component)";
var SWFname = "Software (SWF)";
var L5color = (67 + 212*256 + 255*256*256); 
var SWFcolor = (151 + 231*256 + 255*256*256); 
var GUID = uuidv4();

var description = "@PROP=@NAME=" + SWFname + "@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#=" + SWFcolor + ";#Pen_Color#=0;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT=0@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"
description += "@PROP=@NAME=" + L5name + "@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE@ENDTYPE;@VALU=#Back_Ground_Color#=" + L5color + ";#Pen_Color#=0;#Pen_Size#=1;#Legend_Type#=LEGEND_OBJECTSTYLE;@ENDVALU;@PRMT=1@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"
description += "@PROP=@NAME=Legend@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_STYLE_SETTINGS@ENDTYPE;@VALU=@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"`
```

here I tried to write directly into the SQL Statement:

```
@BACKGROUND=0@ENDBACKGROUND

description += "@PROP=@NAME=Legend@ENDNAME;@TYPE=LEGEND_STYLE_SETTINGS@ENDTYPE;@BACKGROUND=0@ENDBACKGROUND;@VALU=@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;"
    
    var sqlInsertStmt="INSERT INTO t_xref "
    + "(" 
        + "Client,"
        + "XrefID,"
        + "Type,"
        + "Name,"
        + "Visibility,"
        + "Partition,"
        + "Supplier,"
        + "Description"
    + ") "
    + " VALUES ("
        +"'"+legend.ElementGUID+ "',"
        + "'{"+GUID+"}',"
        + "'element property',"
        + "'CustomProperties',"
        + "'Public',"
        + "'0',"
        + "'&lt;none&gt;',"
        + "'"+description+"'"
    + ");"
    ;

    Repository.Execute(sqlInsertStmt);
```

Comment: How did you try to change that? Please post your code.

Comment: There is no documented list. You have to figure it out yourself. You can use another SQL client (e.g. AnySQL Maestro) to query the database; or simply use the SQL scratchpad in EA.

Comment: @GeertBellekens is this part of a new EA Revision? I don´t find a SQL scratchpad/ Database builder under Specialize->Tools

Comment: No, it's part of the model search: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_navigation/creating_filters.html

Comment: Thanks, I got it! The solution was in the t_xref table, where I just manually made the legend through the gui to see the correct properties and copied out them out.

Comment: You are not supposed to add the solution to your question, I rolled back your edit. It's perfectly fine to add an answer yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. The "CustomProperties" in t_xref got me on the right track.

When you have retrieved your Legend element you can issue

```
cp = element.customProperties.getAt(0)
```

There should be only one entry in the collection.

```
cp.name
```

should echo "Legend" and

```
cp.value
```

something like

```
'#TITLE#=Legend;#HEADINGSIZE#=16;#FONTCOLOR#=6303744;#BACKGROUNDCOLOR#=16777215;#BORDERCOLOR#=0;#BACKGROUNDISDEFAULT#=0;'
```

Now you can alter that `cp.value` and once you call `element.update()` you are done. Any diagram showing the legend needs a reload.

Comment: Sadly this doesn´t work for legends, but the solution was in the t_xref table. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't look there. EA changed the object table so I thought that was enough. Seems to be just redundancy. Will cross check and update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Made an update to my answer. Seems you don't need to directly fiddle with t_xref.